# Drawing an "arrow" in the legend of an R plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a **"curve"** and an upright positioned **"arrow"** in an R plot (**see R code Below**).

I was wondering if it might be possible to show an **actual arrow** in the **"legend"** **rather than** a smooth, **straight line to distinguish my arrow from the curve?**

**Here is my R code:**

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, lwd = 3)

arrows(2, 0, 2, .3, code = 2, lwd = 3, col = 'red4')

legend("topleft", legend = c("Curve", "Arrow"), lwd = 3, col = c(1, "red4"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work

```
windows(width = 6, height = 6)
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, lwd = 3)
arrows(2, 0, 2, .3, code = 2, lwd = 3, col = 'red4')

#Get the co-oridnates of extremes
extremes = par("usr")

#Determine how 'long' the lines should be in legend
xx = (extremes[2] - extremes[1])/16 #Change as necessary
yy = (extremes[4] - extremes[3])/16 #Change as necessary

#Draw lines and arrows
lines(x = c(extremes[1]+xx, extremes[1]+2*xx),
    y = c(extremes[4]-yy, extremes[4]-yy),
    lwd = 3)

arrows(x0 = extremes[1]+xx, x1 = extremes[1]+2*xx,
    y0 = extremes[4]-2*yy, y1 = extremes[4]-2*yy,
    code = 2,
    lwd = 3,
    col = 'red4')

#Labels for legend
lab = c("Line", "Arrow")

#Write labels in legend
text(x = c(extremes[1]+2*xx,extremes[1]+2*xx),
    y = c(extremes[4]-yy, extremes[4]-2*yy),
    labels = lab,
    pos = 4)

#Maximum string width of labels
bx = max(strwidth(lab))*1.5

#Draw polygon
polygon(x = c(extremes[1], extremes[1]+2*xx+bx, extremes[1]+2*xx+bx, extremes[1]),
    y = c(extremes[4], extremes[4], extremes[4]-(length(lab)+1)*yy, extremes[4]-(length(lab)+1)*yy))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to put a right arrow in your legend in place of the line. You have to access font = 5 with `par` to get an arrow symbol.

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, lwd = 3)
arrows(2, 0, 2, .3, code = 2, lwd = 3, col = 'red4')
legend("topleft", legend = c("Curve", "Arrow"), pch = c(NA, NA),
       lwd = 3, col = c(1, "red4"),
       lty = c(1, NA)) #normal legend. Do not plot line
par(font = 5) #change font to get arrows
legend("topleft", legend = c(NA, NA), pch = c(NA, 174),
       lwd = 3, col = c(1, "red4"),
       lty = c(1, NA), bty = "n") 
par(font = 1) #back to default
```

[image]

Comment: Heads up that `font = 5` changes the rest of your text to Greek characters, so you _do_ indeed need to split this into two `legend` calls